# What does unmixed mean?

Tags: aerodynamics, jet-engine

For a unmixed turbofan engine what does ‘unmixed’ mean in regards to the flow of air?  How does this differ from ‘mixed’ also in terms of air flow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this refers to the cowling design where a mixed flow the fan and gas core streams mix inside the cowling whereas in unmixed streams the fan air excites the cowling without mixing with the gas core exhaust gases.